# How to use filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following data

```
var data = [
    {
        "h_id": "31",
        "city": "hill",
    },
    {
        "h_id": "13",
        "city": "Bevery Hills",
    },
    {
        "h_id": "5",
        "city": "New York",
    },
    {
        "h_id": "31",
        "city": "New York",
    },
    {
        "h_id": "5",
        "city": "New York",
    }
];
```

I am getting data in this format

```
var data1 = [
    {
        "h_id": "31",
        "city": "hill",
    }, {
        "h_id": "13",
        "city": "Bevery Hills",
    }, {
        "h_id": "31",
        "city": "New York",
    }
];
```

I want data in this format

```
var data1 = [
    {
        "h_id": "31",
        "city": "hill",
    }, {
        "h_id": "31",
        "city": "Bevery Hills",
    }
];
```

This is my angularjs script

```
$scope.data1 = $filter('filter')($scope.data , {h_id:31} )
```

I want the data to be filter based on exact match.filter concept i used above not filtering based on exact match.

Comment: This page documents how to create your own angular filter https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

If its a filter for checking `h_id` of an object you could create a `h_id` filter and pass it your Array of objects as the first param and the `ID` as the second param and then in your `$filter` use YOUR_ARRAY.filter(item => item.hi_id === ID PARAM)

Comment: I want to match exact id.@AlekseySolovey

Comment: Loop your data in controller and assign proper ID

Comment: @selvakumar your examples don't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get results matching certain condition.

```js
var data = [{
  "h_id": "31",
  "city": "hill",
}, {
  "h_id": "13",
  "city": "Bevery Hills",
}, {
  "h_id": "5",
  "city": "New York",
}, {
  "h_id": "31",
  "city": "New York",
}, {
  "h_id": "5",
  "city": "New York",
}];

var newData = data.filter(el => el.h_id==="31");
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the third parameter to strict comparison:

`$scope.data1 = $filter('filter')($scope.data , {h_id:31}, true )`

Here you have the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)